# WKWebView auto zoom for some time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView, For some time it auto zoom . But i disabled all zoom.Here is my code :

```
class overviewViewcontroller: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate,WKUIDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {
var webView1 = WKWebView()

// also In my viewdid load

            webView1.backgroundColor = .white
            webView1.navigationDelegate = self
            webView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            webView1.uiDelegate = self
            webView1.navigationDelegate = self
            webView1.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
            webView1.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            webView1.scrollView.delegate = self
           // webView1.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 0
          //  webView1.scrollView.setZoomScale(0, animated: false)
            webView1.scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
            webView1.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
            webView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            webView1.scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false





 func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
       scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Its happening for some time only.Not able to reproduce every time.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints true and add auto-resizing mask with frame -

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] 
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```